# Even with all bone transformations cleared, as soon as my rig is in pose mode, it distorts my model

Tags: modifiers, rigging, pose-mode

I've tried a lot of different fixes for this, but it has happened to me many times. Everything looks fine in rest mode, but as soon as I switch to pose, it distorts the positions of certain parts of the mesh, such as the eye. Clearing all transformations doesn't do anything, and I've checked multiple times that all the bones are visible. For some reason, applying the pose to rest tends to fix this issue, but it comes back on occasion.

Additionally, at some point, without changing anything, the rig started controlling the wrong parts of the mesh--with the eyebrow denting the middle of the head, for example, while many still work fine. I've tried all different ways of fixing this but been unable to succeed. I feel like it might be connected to the way the skin mesh is attached to the eyebrows (again, something that is unclear, since I cleared parenting and made sure there weren't any deform modifiers).

On said topic-- the eyebrows are created using a mesh deform cage on some lines, which then has a surface deform o some planes. It has repeatedly told me "target has edges with more than two polygons" and I've tried all the cleanup tools, even remeshes in voxels and blocks, just to experiment, but nothing has fixed it, so I'm not sure how to find those edges.

I am new to blender, learning off of youtube videos and etcetera, but this seems like a bit of a trainwreck.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to a similar issue I had was that I had left over vertex groups from parented to the metarig and it deformed the character after I parented it to the created rig. I had to delete all the non DEF vertex groups (associated with the bones, not other vertex groups that I created).